# mock google ads get_type or get_service method python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api

What is the best way to mock the Google Ads Client, `get_type` or `get_service` function?
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/proto-getters

For example:

```
user_data = self.google_ads_client.get_type("UserData")
user_identifier = self.google_ads_client.get_type("UserIdentifier")
user_identifier.hashed_email = email
```

I want to mock the return for `user_data` and `user_identifier`, but I'm finding it difficult to setup the right mock.